# SVG in HTML with a script element

Tags: html, svg

I have an inline SVG code inside a HTML page,

```
<body>
<div style="width:1000px;height:1000px">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svgcanvas" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="viewport">
<circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
<script xlink:href="js/SVGPan.js" type="text/javascript"/>
</svg>
```

The script is invoked correctly in Firefox 7.0, but not in Chrome 16.0. Why is this so? And what modifications should I make in the code to invoke the javascript in Chrome too?

Comment: FWIW, I currently advocate [SVG in XHTML](http://phrogz.net/svg/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml), not SVG in HTML.

Comment: Yes. This is just a simple code which I am trying out for a college project.

Comment: @Phrogz is there any advantages for SVG in HTML5 comparing to XHTML? I mean for SVG support because HTML4 generates so much headache with SVG.

Comment: @Alex: I think he means you'd be better off using [the XML serialization of HTML5](http://www.w3.org/QA/2008/01/html5-is-html-and-xml.html) if you're going to embed SVG (and MathML, I suppose). I can't speak for Phrogz, but I'd say the same thing based on the fact that it "feels right" to embed XML (which is what SVG is) in XML rather than some other SGML dialect (which is what HTML5 is in its HTML serialization).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `<script></script>` instead of `<script/>`, I've had problems with this before.

Comment: Did it work? Then please mark this as the correct reply by clicking the check-mark to the left of my reply.

Comment: @EmilStenström - A quick test shows that it does work (+1), though for quite a curious reason. See my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting question.

Some things to note.

Inside normal HTML, `<script ... />` would not be self closing and anything that followed would be part of the contents of the script element.

Inside the `<svg>` element, `<script ... />` is self closing and forms an entire element.

Both Firefox and Chrome get this right.

However, the HTML5 spec says that the script should only be **processed** when the parser encounters the end tag. Since the element doesn't have an end tag, then, the script should not be processed. This is what Chrome does.

The SVG spec however, requires the script to be run once the element has been closed by any means, not just on an end tag. This is what Firefox does.

IMHO, the HTML5 spec is wrong, and should specify behaviour consistent with SVG.

**UPDATE: 10 Aug 2012.**

The HTML5 spec (currently [WHATWG version](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage//tree-construction.html#parsing-main-inforeign) only) has been changed so that the SVG script should be run. See https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=17995

**UPDATE: 16 Sep 2012.**

The W3C version of the HTML5 spec has now also been corrected.

Comment: This difference stems from the fact that SVG is an XML dialect, and HTML5 is SGML with special processing rules. Embedding SVG in HTML5 has to conform to the *HTML5* syntax (doing it the other way around would make no sense). If you find this annoying, use the XML serialization of HTML5 in which I would expect self-closing `script` elements to work (although I cannot find the relevant part of the HTML5 specification ATM).

Comment: Hmmm thanks! Am just entering into the world of SVG. Your answer has cleared up a lot of things. On a personal note I feel that the world of SVG and HTML DOM should be somewhat streamlined a lot more than it is currently. But thanks again for a clear explanation :)

Comment: @You - No, The HTML5 spec could be fixed quite easily. In the section 8.2.5.5 The rules for parsing tokens in foreign content, it just needs an additional clause that says "A start tag whose tag name is "script", if the current node is an element in the SVG namespace ..." which then repeats the requirements for "Any other start tag", except the last line is changed to say "If the token has its self-closing flag set, acknowledge the token's self-closing flag and act as if an end tag with the same tag name as the current node had been seen"

Comment: @Alohci: But `script` having radically different processing rules depending on context would be a source of confusion. IMHO, it's better to have the same rules *everywhere* and have some incompatibilities with SVG (HTML5 is not XML after all) than to have different rules in the SVG context leading to confusion. (+1 for the research by the way, it is interesting to know that things work like this)

Comment: @You - I guess it depends on what one thinks of as different rules. If the rule is "the script is run only when the script close tag is parsed" then I agree. If the rule is "the script is run just after its end element event occurs", then the different behaviour is currently what's specified in HTML5. Given the different parsing requirements for in foreign content both rules cannot apply.